# decode raw data from 802.11 Radiotap

Tags: python, sockets, wifi, radiotap

I trying to create small monitor mode sniffer in python, the sniffer have to print on the screen 4 parameters, SSID, Srouce MAC, RSSI, Frequency, i used socket library cuz Scapy doesn't parsing Radiotap.

in my case get this hexdump :

```
0000   00 00 1A 00 2F 48 00 00  73 B7 E3 38 67 01 00 00   ..../H..s..8g...
0010   10 02 7B 09 C0 00 AE 00  00 00 80 00 00 00 FF FF   ..{.............
0020   FF FF FF FF 00 1B 9E A8  1D 6E 00 1B 9E A8 1D 6E   .........n.....n
0030   F0 FC 08 60 69 8F 24 00  00 00 64 00 11 04 00 05   ...`i.$...d.....
0040   41 72 6F 6D 61 01 08 82  84 8B 96 24 30 48 6C 03   Aroma......$0Hl.
0050   01 06 05 04 00 01 00 04  2A 01 04 2F 01 04 32 04   ........*../..2.
0060   0C 12 18 60 DD 0E 00 50  F2 04 10 4A 00 01 10 10   ...`...P...J....
0070   44 00 01 01 DD 09 00 10  18 02 04 F0 00 00 00 DD   D...............
0080   18 00 50 F2 01 01 00 00  50 F2 02 01 00 00 50 F2   ..P.....P.....P.
0090   02 01 00 00 50 F2 02 0C  00 DD 18 00 50 F2 02 01   ....P.......P...
00a0   01 80 00 03 A4 00 00 27  A4 00 00 42 43 5E 00 62   .......'...BC^.b
00b0   32 2F 00 C6 93 C8 81                               2/.....
```

in the second line (0010) the 3nd and 4nd byte is 7B 09 show us the correct frequency, in this case 2412mHz,

here the question, how can i convert this hex to correct frequency ? 
I found this page http://www.radiotap.org/defined-fields/Channel

but not success =\ 
can somebody know how to convert this hex to correct Frequency ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

The two bytes is first contain the channel "7B" the 2nd "09" is static. 
I take the first and encode to hax (from raw data) and convert on base 16 to value i add 2304 and we got the frequency

python:

```
int(pkt[18].encode('hex'), 16)+2304)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the struct library to unpack the values rather than simple indexing and remember the 2nd byte 0x09 is the channel flags.